# simple code view by Cheat Engine, but nothing found

Tags: cheat-engine

I want to find integer value `code_injct` on cheat engine and modify this value 43369 or else

here is my code

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <Windows.h>
int main() {
    int code_injct = 43971;

    while (1){      
        printf("%d\n", code_injct);     
        Sleep(5000);
    }
}
```

and I try run Cheat Engine, attach process `Project1.exe, scan 43971.`

But there is nothing found. What I missed?

[image: screenshot]

Answer (score 1):

Please, test with the newest version of Cheat Engine 6.8.3

When testing with newest version, please test with the .exe in the Visual Studio output folder, don't run the .exe from Visual Studio.

Make sure you're using VEH debugger, go to CE options -> Debugger Options -> Use VEH Debugger

If it's still not working, when selecting which window you want to inject, attach the debugger to the current process.

If none of this things are working, could you please update your question with your CE settings?

Answer (score 0):

You're attached to the wrong process.  You need to attach to the actual executable file, not the VS debug console.